# Found nil while unwrapping and optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am having unwrapping error when i was click sign in button for logging to my web service  from my sign in view controller.I set two text field and one button at Sign In View Controller.I dont know what is wrong with me.I comment the line that i got the following error

This is my Sign In View Controller

```
class SignInViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var userEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!

var api : AccountAPI?
var email : String?
var password : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.removeNavigationBarItem()

    // Force the device in portrait mode when the view controller gets loaded
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

}

@IBAction func signInTapped(){

    println("Tapped")

// Error Occur After This Line
        api!.signIn(["email" : "example@gmail.com", "passwd" : "12345"], url: "http://localhost:8080/ws/xxx/xxx/xxxx") { (succeeded: String, msg: String) -> () in
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success!", message: "Nothing!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay.")

            if(succeeded == "ok") {
                alert.title = "Success!"
            }
            else {
                alert.title = "Failed :("
            }
            // Move to the UI thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                // Show the alert
                alert.show()
            })
        }

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.removeNavigationBarItem()

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    // Lock autorotate
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {

    // Only allow Portrait
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {

    // Only allow Portrait
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}

}
```

And this is My Account API

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AccountAPI{

func createStringFromDictionary(dict: Dictionary<String,String>) -> String {
    var params = String()
    for (key, value) in dict {
        params += "&" + key + "=" + value
    }
    return params
}

func signIn(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: String, msg: String) -> ()) {

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params2 = createStringFromDictionary(params)
    var paramsLength = "\(countElements(params2))"
    var requestBodyData = (params2 as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        var msg = "No message"

        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            postCompleted(succeeded: "not_ok", msg: "Error")
        }
        else {

            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                if let success = parseJSON["status"] as? String {
                    println("Succes: \(success)")
                    postCompleted(succeeded: success, msg: "Logged in.")
                }
                return
            }
            else {

                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                postCompleted(succeeded: "not_ok", msg: "Error")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}

}
```

Any Help,Please.

Comment: Where are you creating / setting the `api`?

Comment: ^ what Wain said. I am scanning your code and I don't see api initialized anywhere. As far as we're concerned, api is nil and it should crash.

Comment: Surely the debugger will stop exactly at the line where the unwrapping crashed your app. And surely at that point you can examine the variables and see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: What do u mean Kelvin Lau?I dont understand what u want to say clearly

Comment: @htarwara6245

You have a `api` instance variable of type `AccountApi?`. The question mark means `api` is initially initialized to nil. Unless you initialize `api` and allocate memory to it, it will stay nil. 

As far as I can tell, you never initialize `api`. So when a user taps the button and executes your IBAction, it will crash when you force unwrap `api`. 

`api!.signIn...` will crash because api is nil.

Comment: @gnasher729,it was api:AccountAPI.That is the one which is causing me Nil.I comment like error this // Error Occur After This Line

Comment: @Kelvin Lau,How do i solve this.u r right.Also i am newbie to swift

Comment: @Kelvin Lau,Thanks for your excellent answer.I got this now.I forgot to initialized my api variable.And One more question,how can u explain between "!" & "?",i am not still clear of these two optional terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api` variable is not initialized. You should do that before the the user can tap on the sign button.

Try putting in viewDidLoad `api = AccountAPI()`

Comment: Thanks.I got this now...I see i don't initialize my Api variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the api variable set anywhere. You should set it before the user is able to tap the button, since you're force-unwrapping it. Or, you could validate the value of api, and return if nil, before doing the api call.

Comment: Thanks @DarkDust, I will rephrase.